# How to fix messed up vertices after sculpting a model

Tags: modifiers, vertices, sculpting

I just started learning to sculpt a model in blender. When I was finished and had switched to edit mode, I ran into a problem
[image]

A lot of the vertices were messed up like this. The decimate modifier just messes it up even more.
[image]

Is there any way to fix this, I am kinda new to sculpting so I have no idea?

Comment: There is nothing to fix, you'd have to retopo you're sculpt anyway. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CuQzPDs99yM

Comment: if you're planning to sculpt it further, you don't need to improve the topology, and if you want to create a low-poly version (aka retopology) you don't need either, so in any case you should not need to improve the topology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use remesh modifier or remesh option from properties or any other tool like instant mesh

**Mesh at start:**
[image]

**Remesh Modifier:(make sure not to drag voxel size too quickly or blender will crash)**
[image]

**Remesh option in blender:**

[image]

**Result of remesh option:**
[image]